# Shiny dashboard rendering breaks in Firefox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a R-shiny dashboard. It runs well as standalone program. However, as I open it in Firefox browser, it kind of breaks.

Figure one shows how it looks as a standalone program. And figure two shows how it looks on Firefox.

Here is the code that produces the part.

```
 sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(   
   sidebarMenu(

   menuItem("My Shiny",  tabName = "twebuddies_uhg", icon = icon("twitter-square"), 
              badgeLabel = "Info", badgeColor = "red" ),

 more menues
```

I appreciate your time and effort in helping with this. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this abnormal behaviour?

Comment: Hi, I am afraid that I could not find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use [runtime](/questions/tagged/runtime) option in the head of document and specify the runtime.

Here some links of reference:

1. [flexdashboard/shiny.html](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html)
2. [shiny_prerendered.html](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html)

Try to use the runtime option (in the head of document) as below:

```
---
title: "Name of App"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard 
runtime: shiny # Or shiny_prerendered
---
```